# Display product images from a loop using django

Tags: python, django

I would like to display my images from a loop, my images are stored on static/images and in the database the image field is a CharField of image name.

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   BASE_DIR / 'static',
]
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='account:profile'
LOGIN_URL='account:login'
```

models.py

```
 class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=70,blank=True,null=True)
    price=models.IntegerField()
    image=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
```

views.py

```
{% load static %}
{% for product in products %}
   <div class="card">
     <div class="card-image">
        <img src="{% static 'images/{{product.image}}' %}">     
    </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't display the image. How to do ??

Comment: Inspect in the browser, web page source code the imaga tag if it forms the correct src link,

Comment: I checked this is what is showing: <img src="None">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using charfield, use this:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/' %}{{product.image}}">
```

Comment: image field is chartype so product.image.url will not work. And static image will be same for all the elements.

Comment: It is chartype correct, but it has its attributes such as url.  Have a look at point number 3 here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/faq/usage/#how-do-i-use-image-and-file-fields

Comment: Also, you can try this, if you are using charfield: `<img src="{% static 'images/' %}{{product.image}}">`

Comment: We use .url for file or media we uploaded. If we are using CharField and url in that CharField then we can only get it by product.image.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Kindly take note.